# How to replicate a Razer Synapse "Play while assigned key is pressed" Macro in Python

Tags: python, pynput

I'm trying to replicate a razor synapse "Play while assigned key is pressed" macro in python but I don't know what modules I will need ( I'm new to python )

I have worked out the math and will post my code below +  a picture of how it looks in razer synapse to compare. Note - I don't know how to send keys, as again, I'm unsure what modules I need.

How it looks in razer synapse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgdj8.jpg

So when I press & hold "Spacebar" it will loop "Left Button Down & Left Button Up" 0.2 wait then "Right Button Down & Right Button Up" 0.234 wait > until I release.

The code I currently have with the math figured out:

```
s = 2.5 #Static
p = 0.034 #Static
LeftClickDelay = 0.2 #Static
RightClickDelay  = (1/s) /2 + (p)
```

Any insight/help would be much appreciated

Kind regards,

MaggotMike

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pynput](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput) package to simulate keyboard/mouse input using Python. You should `listen` for when <kbd>spacebar</kbd> is pressed and then trigger the mouse clicks with necessary delays.

This [post](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/simulate-keypresses-in-python/) might be helpful in getting you started. Also, check out the documentation for `pynput` [here](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) for how to `listen` for key presses.